# Short way for tests validations in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I want a simple way to test my validations. My test focus are integrations, not validations, and I don't working with TDD. That being said, I want to replace:

```
# Estate model specs

describe "#name" do
  it "is required" do
    estate.name = nil
    estate.valid?
    expect(estate.errors).to have_key(:name)
  end
end

describe "#company" do
  it "is required" do
    estate.company = nil
    estate.valid?
    expect(estate.errors).to have_key(:company)
  end
end

# and so on..
```

to some like:

```
# Estate model specs

requiredFields = [:name, :company, :price, :region, :regions, :typologies, :image]
requiredFields.each do |requiredField|
  describe "##{requiredField}" do
    it "is required" do
      estate[requiredField] = nil
      estate.valid?
      expect(estate.errors).to have_key(requiredField)
    end
  end
end
```

The fields name and price works, the problem is in associations:

```
Estate
  is an instance of Estate
  validations
    with required fields
      should be valid
    #name
      is required
    #company
      is required (FAILED - 1)
    #price
      is required
    #region
      is required (FAILED - 2)
    ...
```

I think that problem is `estate[requiredField]`. If I change to company_id will work. How can I do something like `estate.requiredField` in foreach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform `estate.requiredField` using Ruby's [`send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-send) method, which invokes its argument as a method on the receiver:

```
estate.send(requiredField)
```

Since you're assigning, you'll need to interpolate an `=` into the field name. The `foo=` method takes an argument, which you pass as continued arguments to `send` after the method name:

```
estate.send("#{requiredField}=", nil)`
```

Something to be aware of is that since `send` ends up calling the requested method from within the receiver, you might end up bypassing `protected` or `private` methods.

```
class Dog
   private
   def bark
     puts 'Woof'
   end
 end

Dog.new.bark
# NoMethodError: private method 'bark' called for #<Dog:0x007fd28bad7590>

Dog.new.send :bark
# Woof
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `object.send`

```
estate.send("#{requiredField}=", value) # setter, estate.requiredField=value
estate.send(requiredField) # getter, estate.requiredField
```

Or use https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers for such kind of tests